# Java ECDH Base64 Serialization Consumption

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, ecdh

I am trying to turn a Base64 public and private ECDH key back into the `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` type. I generate my serialized keys like this:

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "SunEC");
        ECGenParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec(secp256r1);
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecParameterSpec);
        KeyPair ecdhKeyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = ecdhKeyPair.getPublic();

        String pubKeyString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
        String privKeyString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded());
```

However, my methods to turn the base64 serialized key back to their `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` formats throw some exceptions. Here are the methods I wrote to do those conversions:

```
private static PublicKey generatePublicECDHKeyFromBase64(String base64EncryptedECDHKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncryptedECDHKey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");

    return kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
}

private static PrivateKey generatePrivateECDHKeyFromBase64(String base64EncryptedECDHKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncryptedECDHKey);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");

    return kf.generatePrivate(X509publicKey);
}
```

The exception I get thrown looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
    at com.vendify.temp.temp(temp.java:43)
    at com.vendify.BackendDbApplication.main(BackendDbApplication.java:9)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:170)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:389)
    at com.vendify.temp.generatePrivateECDHKeyFromBase64(temp.java:60)
    at com.vendify.temp.temp(temp.java:33)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerValue.getBigIntegerInternal, not expected 48
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:135)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.<init>(PKCS8Key.java:95)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl.<init>(ECPrivateKeyImpl.java:75)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.implGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:245)
    at jdk.crypto.ec/sun.security.ec.ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(ECKeyFactory.java:166)
    ... 4 more
```

I am a bit new to this, always just used the basic classes haha, so sorry for the super basic question. I would love to hear the solutions you guys got for this :)

Comment: I created an example using your code and it ran just fine. Most likely your are somehow corrupting the base64 strings after they are created but before they make it into your `generateXYZ` methods.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Did you attempt to run the methods: generatePrivateECDHKeyFromBase64(privKeyString); and generatePublicECDHKeyFromBase64(pubKeyString );? That should give the errors I am talking about :). If the Base64 was corrupted, my exception should be triggering when I attempt to decode the base64, but it seems to corrupt at the kf.generatePrivate(X509publicKey) lines.

Comment: Corruption of base64 does NOT always cause decoding to fail. Check your data. I agree with (ex)Prez Jimmy this works with correct data. PS: calling base64 'encrypted' is false and may harmfully deceive people, though the compiler and JVM ignore it.

Comment: Interesting, ill give it a shot shortly, thanks!